# How to receive a notification when send a message

Tags: flutter, getstream-io, localnotification

Has anyone ever used gestream and flutter local notification so that when one sends a message, the recipient receives a notification?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement push notification in your app

Comment: Please how do we do that? Which dart file do we edit?

Comment: it's a long process, refer some tutorials online, on youtube or some tutorial website, you can type this " how to implement push notification in flutter"

Answer (score 0):

See the Stream documentation on Push Notification: https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/flutter/guides/adding_push_notifications_v2/

And here are legacy docs for the V1 push notification logic: https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/flutter/guides/adding_push_notifications/

Some additional documentation if you need extra info: https://getstream.io/chat/docs/flutter-dart/push_introduction/?language=dart#push-delivery-rules